# How to increase array size and add every new element on the top of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

Do you know how to increase dynamically the size of the array with new elements and every new element goes on the top of the array in Java?

I am having this Java snippet:

```
    List<String> dbsuggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...some for loop here



    String correctedText = correctMedicalAcronym(ac, classify, c);

    if(correctedText != null){
        System.out.println(correctedText);
        dbsuggestions.add(0, correctedText);
    }   

    ...end of the for loop
```

Comment: `ArrayList` takes care of increasing array size dynamically. You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @GautamSavaliya yeah but if he need to add every time an element is better to use linkedlist...

Comment: if you want to add element on top (so the new elemnt be the first element), maybe you should consider using a Stack. Use the [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) for a stack implementation.

Comment: What is wrong, it seems like this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how to increase dynamically the size of the array with new
>   elements and every new element goes on the top of the array in Java?

You can use `List`, all of it's implementations will take care of increasing the size dynamically as per requirements. If you want every new element to go on top and while removing, you also pop always from top, I will recommend, you go through [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

It's the contract of `Stack` to put every element on top and remove every element from top. Forexample:

```
        Stack<String> stackDemo = new Stack<>();
        stackDemo.push("First");
        stackDemo.push("Second");
        stackDemo.push("Third");
        System.out.println(stackDemo.pop()); // will return Third
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how to increase dynamically the size of the array with new
>   elements and every new element goes on the top of the array in Java?

Maybe you don't need of an array. Try to look at lists.

Array is static structure, when you declare you fixed is dimension. If you need to add new elements every time in the top. You should use Lists.

Otherwise there are other strategies that you can use like declare an array bigger than what you need and to full it with criteries in way to avoid to realloce it every time.

---

Should I use LinkedList or ArrayList. It depends on what you need:

For `LinkedList<E>`

- `get(int index)` is O(n)
- `add(E element)` is O(1)
- `add(int index, E element)` is O(n)
- `remove(int index)` is O(n) --- `remove(0)` is O(1)
- `Iterator.remove()` is O(1) <--- main benefit of LinkedList
- `ListIterator.add(E element)` is O(1) <--- main benefit of
  LinkedList

For `ArrayList<E>`

- `get(int index)` is O(1) <--- main benefit of ArrayList
- `add(E element)` is O(1) amortized, but O(n) worst-case since the array
  must be resized and copied
- `add(int index, E element)` is O(n - index) amortized, but O(n)
  worst-case (as above)
- `remove(int index)` is O(n - index) (i.e. removing last is O(1))
- `Iterator.remove()` is O(n - index)
- `ListIterator.add(E element)` is O(n - index)

So choose your structure carefully!

Comment: ArrayList is a List implemented with an Array, so it is also static. You should use LinkedList

Comment: @granmirupa that is nonsense. ArrayList does use an array, but the size can change. You should not use a LinkedList, unless there is a specific reason to.

Comment: @matt yeah the size can change.. But you think that change the size costs O(1)??? ArrayList use strategies to amortize is cost when you add new elements. But it never will be O(1) differently from LinkedList. If you have to do a lot of inserts I hint LinkedList.

Comment: First off your argument was that the ArrayList doesn't change size. I never said anything about performance and neither did you. Adding to an ArrayList can be quite fast, and much faster than adding to a LinkedList, especially since the size of the backing array does not have to be the size of the list. Maybe inserting to the first element is faster, but I wouldn't believe it without testing it.

Comment: We have not enough information to know either way. Does the task involve random access? etc. Adding only to the top sounds like a stack, though, but even that depends...

Comment: @user2670818 yes, why shouldn't?